# Using .Net Membership Provider in conjunction with Entity Framework 4.3 migrations

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership, entity-framework-4.3

I'm working on an application where so far we have been managing the database and domain via Entity Framework 4.3 code first with migrations...

As seen here...
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/09/ef-4-3-code-based-migrations-walkthrough.aspx

We have come to the point of needing to implement membership and are wanting to use .NET Membership provider.  In the past I have just used aspnet_regsql.exe to generate all the membership tables in the database.  Is there a way to make it so these membership tables get generated in the database as part of one of the migrations?

Comment: I would suggest that you try using the aspnet_regsql generation and then do a create-migration to see if it captures the delta. Since you're using migrations you should be able to do this to a new version of your application's DB instance pretty painlessly....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you can use the class SqlServices to install the services:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.management.sqlservices.install.aspx

Example:

```
SqlServices.Install ("databaseName", SqlFeatures.Membership, yourConnectionString); 
SqlServices.Install ("databaseName", SqlFeatures.RoleManager, yourConnectionString);
```

I hope I was helpful.